# Hangfire on Azure SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, hangfire

I just published an Azure Website using an Azure SQL.

However, I get the error

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

when reaching the website, with the callback related to Hangfire:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +830
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +329
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +507
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +217
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.CreateAndOpenConnection() +49
   Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection(Func`2 func) +41
   Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseTransaction(Func`2 func, Nullable`1 isolationLevel) +84
   Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseTransaction(Action`1 action) +73
   Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerWriteOnlyTransaction.Commit() +47
   Hangfire.RecurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(String recurringJobId, Job job, String cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo timeZone, String queue) +277
```

Any idea?

Comment: do you get these errors often? If no, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34413504/6326116)

Comment: Sadly now, it's the initial deploy of the web apps. It just don't work, and I get this error, using /hangfire url

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. If you, like me, copied the connection string from Azure Portal database settings page, try removing `Pooling=False;`. This fixed the issue for me.

Sorry, I don't have a good explanation of why this was causing Hangfire to fail. But normally, you would want to have connection pooling enabled anyway.

Comment: Can you share your overall experience using hang fire with SQL azure db?

Comment: Did you have to increase the default polling interval or roll your own kind of retry or fault tolerance logic?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I was just experimenting with moving one of the existing applications to Azure Web Apps, so I cannot say that I have had a lot of experience using Hangfire with Azure SQL other than it worked as expected. And we only use it to send email notifications in background, so there's not a lot of requirements for fault tolerance. As for polling interval, I did not have to change the default one.